# Visual Studios adding folder to release directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xulrunner

I am trying to pull in a dependency, xulrunner to be exact. It is basically a folder of binaries and an executable called xulrunner.exe. The code initializes xulrunner for use by passing in the location of xulruner.exe to an api of another dll that my program uses.

How do I get visual studios to copy over the entire directory of xulrunner to the release folder on build so I can package xulrunner with my program and use a relative address when specifying the file path to xulrunner.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Post-build & Pre-build events to a project in visual studio. Go to the properties of the project and there will be a tab called 'Build Events'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx

Should give you the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Dragged the folder into the visual studios project.

Manually edited the folder entry in the csproject to do a recursive copy with "**"

Set the copy mode to Always